# preventDefault() and 2 functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On my website users can add a text dynamically and remove it dynamically (via AJAX).

The problem is when users want to add a text and remove it immediately.
The suppression isn't realized (submit of deletion form is not detected).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
        /* ADD A TEXT */
        $("#formAdd").submit(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var text = $(this).find("textarea").val();
            if (text) {                 
                var url = $(this).attr('action'); 
                form = $(this).serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url  : url,
                    dataType : "json",
                    data: {
                        "form" : form,
                        "form-type"  : $(this).find(':submit').attr("name")
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        document.getElementById("visualisation").html = text;                               
                    },
                    statusCode: {
                        400: function() {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    }   
                });
            }
        });


        /* REMOVE A TEXT */
        $('#formDelete').submit(function(e) {               
            alert("CHECK !");
            var idText = $(this).find('#text_visualisation').val();

            form = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                dataType : "json",
                data: {
                    'form' : form,
                    "form-type" : $(this).find(':submit').attr("name"),
                },
                success: function(data) {                       
                    $("#text").remove();
                    $("#modal_deleteForm").modal('hide');                                       
                },
                statusCode: {
                    400: function() {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

So the `alert("CHECK !");` is not realized when I want to delete a text just after added this text. Why ?

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear, but do you mean that people click 'delete' while the first AJAX request is in progress, and then the data is added anyway once the request completes?

Comment: No people can only add a text, only delete a text or add and delete a same text (probleme in this case)

Answer (score -2):

I find the solution after a lot of hours of research... The probleme isn't preventDefault() but innerHTML (you couldn't now it, I'm sorry).

But I don't understand why use innerHTML can blocked jquery submission of form...

Thank's